# Only desktop background is showing after minimal install with xfce

Tags: lightdm, xfce, ubuntu-minimal

So, I did a minimal install using minimal iso, and install xfce in it by doing the following.

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

Also, I install lightdm

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

I then reboot the computer and got failed to start session problem when trying to login, so I do :

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-session
```

Reboot and I am able to login, but there is only wallpaper showing. No icons, no panel, even `ctrl + alt + t` doesnt get me terminal. What should I do?

Thanks in advance

edit : Also, I am able to use mouse. Only mouse cursor and wallpaper shows

Comment: You probably just need to add a new panel to the desktop but right clicking

Comment: If you wants to install xfce, I suggest you to *apt remove ubuntu-desktop* and *sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends xubuntu-desktop*

Comment: installing xubuntu-desktop works. I now got a full desktop. Thanks guys

Comment: @Redbob, this comment should be put as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wants to install xfce, I suggest you do this:

```
sudo apt remove ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends xubuntu-desktop
```

So you will have a xfce-based environment. If you prefer a fully-featured installation, just remove `--no-install-recommends` from this command.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I almost gave up but remembered I had chrome remote desktop installed. I logged in remotely and had access to my terminal